# select for update lock releases if the connection is broken or timed out or server down scenario?

Tags: java, oracle, locking

From my ejb am connecting to the Oracle and executing 
Select For UPDATE Query.
Before commit or Roll Back i force killing my server, so no commit or Roll back is called.
Is the select for update lock released after timeout?
For me its not happening.

Comment: See Justin's answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993270/how-can-i-automatically-unlock-tables-in-oracle-after-a-given-time

Comment: In case Justin's answer doesn't clarify things for you, what do you mean by "force killing my server"?  You mean `SHUTDOWN ABORT` on the database server?  `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION...`?  `kill -9` on your Oracle server process? 
 Killing the client application?  The answer will determine when and how locks are released.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak am killing the the client application. My client application is Jboss

Comment: I just run the select for update Query, with out commit or rollback, i close my connection to the DB.

Comment: In that case, you probably do need to set `SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME` as indicated in Justin Cave's answer (linked above).